# Float converted to 2.dp reverts to original number of decimal places when inserted into a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, format, decimal

I have created the following snippet of code and I am trying to convert my 5 dp `DNumber` to a 2 dp one and insert this into a string. However which ever method I try to use, always seems to revert the `DNumber` back to the original number of decimal places (5)

#### Code snippet below:

```
if key == (1, 1):
    DNumber = '{r[csvnum]}'.format(r=row) 
    # returns 7.65321
    DNumber = """%.2f""" % (float(DNumber))
    # returns 7.65
    Check2 = False              
    if DNumber:
        if DNumber <= float(8):
            Check2 = True                    
        if Check2:
            print DNumber 
            # returns 7.65
            string = 'test {r[csvhello]} TESTHERE test'.format(r=row).replace("TESTHERE", str("""%.2f""" % (float(gtpe)))) 
# returns: test Hello 7.65321 test
            string = 'test {r[csvhello]} TESTHERE test'.format(r=row).replace("TESTHERE", str(DNumber))
# returns: test Hello 7.65321 test
```

What I hoped it would return: `test Hello 7.65 test`

Any Ideas or suggestion on alternative methods to try?

Comment: `DNumber = '{r[csvnum]}'.format(r=row)` could be better written as `DNumber = str(row['csvnum'])`. Also, `"""` string notation is used when the string spans multiple lines.  In your case it's probably best to use a single `"` or `'`

Comment: Also, after the second `DNumber` assignment, it's the string `"7.65"`, and `"7.65" <= 8` will always be false in CPython 2.x or raise a `TypeError` in any Python 3.x, because they're of different types.

Comment: Meanwhile, when I run this code, I get exactly what you hoped for. `DNumber` is still the string `"7.65"`, so `str(DNumber)` is the same string, and the `.replace("TESTTHERE", str(DNumber))` replaces `TESTHERE` with `7.65`. If some _different_ code doesn't do what you want, you will have to give us that different code to debug, instead of this code.

Comment: @crennie we tried you version, unfortunately in my code it still managed to revert the number back to the original `float`

Comment: @abarnert This was a mistake in my example, the 8 is also a `float()` (as per changes to the question)

Comment: @abarnert in my real code, `DNumber` somehow reverts back the multiple decimal place `float` As per your second point it again unfortunately reverts.

Comment: @GTPE: The `8` being a `float` instead of an `int` won't make any difference is `DNumber` is a `str` (as it is). (Also, you can just write `8.0`, not `float(8)`, if you want that.) Meanwhile, a variable can't magically change into another type. Obviously you're doing something different—and wrong—in your real code than in the code you've shown us, and we can't possibly tell you what you're doing wrong in code we can't see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you were hoping that converting the float to a 2-decimal-place string and then back to a float would give you a 2-decimal-place float.

The first problem is that your code doesn't actually do that anywhere. If you'd done that, you would get something very close to `7.65`, not `7.65321`.

But the bigger problem is that what you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. A float always has 53 binary digits, no matter what. If you round it to two decimal digits (no matter how you do it, including by converting to string and back), what you actually get is a float rounded to two decimal digits *and then rounded to 53 binary digits*. The closest `float` to `7.65` is not exactly `7.65`, but `7.650000000000000355271368`.* So, that's what you'd end up with. And there's no way around that; it's inherent to the way `float` is stored.

However, there is a *different* type you can use for this: [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). For example:

```
>>> f = 7.65321
>>> s = '%.2f' % f
>>> d = decimal.Decimal(s)
>>> f, s, d
(7.65321, '7.65', Decimal('7.65'))
```

Or, of course, you could just pass around a string instead of a float (as you're accidentally doing in your code already), or you could remember to use the `.2f` format every time you want to output it.

---

As a side note, since your `DNumber` ends up as a string, this line is not doing anything useful:

```
if DNumber <= 8:
```

In Python 2.x, comparing two values of different types gives you a consistent but arbitrary and meaningless answer. With CPython 2.x, it will always be `False`.** In a different Python 2.x implementation, it might be different. In Python 3.x, it raises a `TypeError`.

And changing it to this doesn't help in any way:

```
if DNumber <= float(8):
```

Now, instead of comparing a `str` to an `int`, you're comparing a `str` to a `float`. This is exactly as meaningless, and follows the exact same rules. (Also, `float(8)` means the same thing as `8.0`, but less readable and potentially slower.)

For that matter, this:

```
if DNumber:
```

… is always going to be true. For a number, `if foo` checks whether it's non-zero. That's a bad idea for `float` values (you should check whether it's within some absolute or relative error range of 0). But again, you don't have a `float` value; you have a `str`. And for strings, `if foo` checks whether the string is non-empty. So, even if you started off with `0`, your string `"0.00"` is going to be true.

---

* I'm assuming here that you're using CPython, on a platform that uses IEEE-754 double for its C `double` type, and that all those extra conversions back and forth between string and float aren't introducing any additional errors.

** The rule is, slightly simplified: If you compare two numbers, they're converted to a type that can hold them both; otherwise, if either value is `None` it's smaller; otherwise, if either value is a number, it's smaller; otherwise, whichever one's type has an alphabetically earlier name is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do the following - combine the formatting with the getter:

```
>>> a = 123.456789
>>> row = {'csvnum': a}
>>> print 'test {r[csvnum]:.2f} hello'.format(r=row)
test 123.46 hello
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number is a 7 followed by five digits, you might want to try:

`print "%r" % float(str(x)[:4])`

where x is the float in question.
Example:

```
>>>x = 1.11111
>>>print "%r" % float(str(x)[:4])
>>>1.11
```

Comment: @abarnert if the original poster always has 5 dp then this would also work for him, i don't see how a working correct answer deserves downvotes...

Comment: @Hyflex: There is no case where this would work but the OP's existing posted code would fail. Meanwhile, there are plenty of cases where this would fail but the OP's existing code would work fine. So, if this doesn't help in any case, and hurts in many cases, and is conceptually a bad thing to do, in what sense is it a correct answer?

Comment: @abarnert You're right, your solution is definitely cleaner, and I wasn't aware of it, thanks.